# Website returns status code 200 even if page does not exist

Tags: python, web-scraping

When checking if a web page exists, it returns a status code of 200 even though the page clearly states it does not exist. For example, searching for a jumble of words:

```
https://www.instagram.com/hbsefhkevvbqave
```

This redirects to a page that says it doesn't exist but still returns a status code of 200.

When I implement this into my code that checks if a username exist or not:

```
import urllib.request

username = input('Enter username: ')
url_instagram = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + username

try:
status_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url_instagram).getcode()
if status_code == 200:
    instagram = True
except urllib.error.HTTPError:
    instagram = False
```

This should return False if the page does not exist but it still returns as True because it is returning 200. I was wondering how I could make sure that if the web page doesn't exist i.e. the username doesn't exist, it would return as False.

Comment: If that's what the server returns then you'll have to parse the content of the page and determine it based on that. Note that it may break once the returned data changes.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/